# Is it safe to assume any errors returned from strconv.Parse* functions must be due to bad input data?

Tags: go, error-handling, strconv

In a recent code review, a reviewer took issue with how I handled the error returned from [`strconv.ParseUint()`](https://pkg.go.dev/strconv#ParseInt). This function is documented to return the converted uint value and an error of the `*strconv.NumError` concrete type. The docs mention two sentinel errors of that type that could be returned ([`ErrSyntax`](https://pkg.go.dev/strconv#pkg-variables) and [`ErrRange`](https://pkg.go.dev/strconv#pkg-variables)), both of which imply bad data was provided to it. According to the function's interface, any other error appears possible as well.

For my use case, I needed to know if the string value I have is worthy of being converted to a uint or not. If `ParseUint` returns an error, and it's one of the sentinel errors, then I got my answer. But if the returned error is neither of those, then I returned it and stopped execution. My reviewer asserted that I should rather assume that *any* error returned from `ParseUint` means I gave it bad data, and there's no need to check against the sentinel errors, that there's no reason to check against the sentinel errors, nor to ever return that error (in my use case). They linked to an example in go's standard libraries where the error from `ParseUint` is treated as a check for bad input data and never returned, and said there are many such examples.

While I can certainly understand that there must exist an algorithm that given good data and sufficient resources will always be able to compute the desired result, the real world does not always match the theoretical ideal. I cannot find anything in the library's documentation that says it does not, and will never, return an error for any other reason but bad data. That the standard library has one and perhaps many such examples is on the one hand reassuring and on the other hand scary, somewhere between "two wrongs don't make a right" with "they're doing it so it must be safe for us to do it too" in the case.

Is this just a case of the library's docs missing a sentence? Or is it good to return the error when it's neither of the two sentinel errors? How should I reason about this?

Comment: @rocka2q - I'm following the first two sentences of your comment but the third seems to contradict them.

Comment: Well, if you think it through ParseUint could **potentially** fail on (i) bad input, (ii) OOM, (iii) being broken like in "returns error but everything is okay, (iv) has some internal crosscheck/validation that raises an error because of some hardware glitch (bitflip by cosmic ray), (v) your machine is under attack and ParsUint no longer execudes the original code. I _think_ these are all the cases which are possible. Now ask yourself what you gain if you treat (i) "bad input" somehow differently than (ii) to (v)?

Comment: (ii) doesn't happen in Go 1.0 to Go 1.21 and it's **unlikely** it will ever happen. (iii) Is **very improbable**. There is basically nothing you can do against (iv) and (v) and there is no obvious way to different them from e.g. (i). I think your reviewer is correct. If you actually need to guard against (ii) to (v) you probably have to call log.Fatal and abort hard, assuming the absolute worst. Most code doesn't fall into that category.

Comment: The sentinel errors are "actionable" (e.g. you could try parsing as a math/big.Int) therefore they are exposed and documented. If you do not want to differentiate on these two errors: Just return the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to assume errors from `strconv.ParseXXX` functions are due to bad input data.

From the documentation page you mentioned:

> The errors that ParseInt returns have concrete type *NumError and include err.Num = s. If s is empty or contains invalid digits, err.Err = ErrSyntax and the returned value is 0; if the value corresponding to s cannot be represented by a signed integer of the given size, err.Err = ErrRange and the returned value is the maximum magnitude integer of the appropriate bitSize and sign.

The way I read this is "any error from strconv.ParseXXX is a `NumError` and it will be either due to invalid digits or a bitsize range error". My understanding is also that godocs attempt to be as complete as possible in outlining the range of expectations for function calls.

Therefore, I think it is safe to assume that these are the *only* errors that you might see come back from `strconv.ParseXXX` functions. If something else came back, I would consider it a documentation bug.

To answer your final question: The pattern you've observed in standard library calls to this function is the correct one. Return the error as a whole and let the caller decide what to do with it. The sentinel errors are to help you know what went wrong and represent the full scope of possible errors from these functions.

Comment: I initially read that documentation sentence differently (i.e. not a complete list of options), but I see how it can be read in the way that you explain (i.e. a complete list of options). Thanks for taking the time to explain it!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a single correct answer.

For most cases, if `ParseUint` returns an error, you assume it is a bad input and return that error. You don't even check if it is one of the two concrete error types. There really is no other error `ParseUint` can logically return. For most self-contained parse/decode/unmarshal functions, all errors are different variations of input errors.

There are cases where you might want to check the exact error type. For example, if `ParseUint` returns `ErrRange` you might want to try parsing it as `big.Int`. Then checking the error type makes sense.

Go's interface implementation might confuse some, especially those who are used to error/exception handling in different languages. Go functions return the interface `error` type to denote an error, not a concrete error. Returning a concrete type for an error from a function causes nothing but trouble. So even if a function can return a single concrete type of error, it is declared to return `error`.